# Using Existing Aggregate Form Data

Tags: google-apps-script

When editting a google form, there a response tab that tracks how many times a given response has been selected.

I'm wondering if there is a method for accessing those specific item counts.

Thanks.

Comment: You can access the results from the spreadsheet and count them, yes

Comment: If you mean a "built-in" method, then "no", you can not get a count of how many times a question was answered a specific way in one step.  It *is* possible to write code that will evaluate all the data, and count the number of times a question has been answered a certain way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time there isn't a built-in method to get the aggregated data shown on the responses tab. You could use a script or a spredsheet to calculate those aggregations.